# Create district boundaries in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, boundaries

How can I create district boundaries in ArcGIS Pro? I work for a youth soccer organization and we have about 9 districts that we oversee
I am just looking for a way to make a base layer with these boundary lines to eventually input some census data for my organization. We want to find where we are not providing soccer for children so we may bring it to them!

Comment: Do the boundaries exist on a paper map that you can scan, georeference and digitize over?  What have you tried?

Comment: And what would the country be?

Comment: @PolyGeo I have tried to trace the districts using county boundary lines, however, when using ArcGis online the tracing is not as accurate as ARCGis Pro. I work on a Mac that is nor compatible with Pro. I do have another pdf file of a map with the boundaries, however I can not edit it in the way I would with ArcGis.

Comment: @TomazicM California, United States.

Comment: If you are using ArcGIS Online why is ArcGIS Pro currently mentioned in your question body, title and tags?  If it was put there incorrectly just [edit] it out and improve your question to mention that you are using ArcGIS Online instead.

Comment: Are these districts US administrative districts or some soccer districts?